# Specifying Twilio Incoming and Outgoing Callbacks using TwiML App

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have a number which I have configured to use a TwiML App. In the App itself, I have set the VoiceURL and StatusCallback on the Voice section.

The issue is, the callback is triggered when there is an incoming call to the Twilio-bought number.

However, if I place an outgoing call from the Twilio-bought number, the callback is not triggered.

Is this the expected behaviour, that the TwiML app callback is only triggered on incoming calls?
If this is not the intended behaviour, any pointers on what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is expected, that statusCallback URL handles only the incoming call leg.

If you are forwarding that call(which creates another call leg), you can use the parameter of the name name of the [Number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) noun to capture events.

If you are using the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) to make an outbound call, it has a statusCallback parameter as well.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand this correctly
1. Incoming calls will use the TwiML app status callback URL
2. Outgoing calls through the rest API will use the statusCallback parameter specified.
3. Number in a TwiML response can also have a statuscallback URL as an attr?

Comment: That is Correct